# marker not showing in React Leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

Added a React Leaflet map to the site. I want to put a custom marker, but now it is not shown on the page. It is always shown in the corner of the map when scrolling. How can this be fixed?

```js
    // Marker

    const Marker = () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div
            className="marker"
            style={{ height: "30px", width: "30px", backgroundColor: "red" }}
          ></div>
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default Marker;


    // Map

    const Map = () => {
      const position = [51.505, -0.09];
      return (
        <div>
          <MapContainer
            center={[51.505, -0.09]}
            zoom={13}
            scrollWheelZoom={false}
            style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100%" }}
          >
            <TileLayer
              attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
              url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            <Marker position={position}></Marker>
          </MapContainer>
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default Map;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My snippet works perfectly, you can try this out:-

```js
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import icon from "leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png";
import L from "leaflet";
import iconShadow from "leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png";

let DefaultIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: icon,
  shadowUrl: iconShadow,
});

L.Marker.prototype.options.icon = DefaultIcon;

<section className="container-fluid p-0">
  <MapContainer center={[23.7934, 90.4064]} zoom={16} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
    <TileLayer
      attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
    <Marker position={[23.7934, 90.4064]}>
      <Popup>My Location</Popup>
    </Marker>
  </MapContainer>
</section>;
```

```css
// css
.leaflet-container{
  height: 500px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can I use multiple markers?

Comment: Sure you can, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71348680/how-to-render-multiple-markers-from-an-array-of-coordinates-in-react-leaflet